# Angular interpolating {{ }} in url params, is there a way to sanitize the url?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular1.6

We have an edge case issue where an external application requires a specific url parameter to be present in the url request to our website:

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?abc=123`

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Example error of {{}}]

Occasionally, the url parameter will not render correctly causing the url to become:

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?abc={{}}`

We have angular running on our application, it cannot parse this causing unnecessary errors for the webpage.

***Does angular have a way of encoding the url before it hits the app?***

#### Details

- Angular 1.6.6

#### Current Solution

We have a temporary `nginx` redirect solution in place but believe its better if we fixed the source of the issue.

We've done a lot of reading into changing the template tags but this is a huge fix.

#### Expected

**We don't use any custom url variables**. We want to it not throw an error and function normally as expected when not parse `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?abc={{}}`

Comment: use `ng-href` which will put href only once the string is parsed

Comment: Are you using Angular or AngularJS? You put both tags to your question but they are different frameworks with different directives. Also, it will be easily to help if you post the HTML code where the link is

Comment: @VirgilioGM I've updated the question with some screenshots, tags and more details. We are currently using angular 1.6.

Answer (score 2):

You need to bind the parameter in `[queryParams]="{ 'abc':'test' }"`

Since a object needs to be passed, you can create the object dynamically in typescript.

Try like this:

**HTML**:

```
<a [routerLink]="['https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask']" [queryParams]="getQueryParam()">Link</a>
```

**TS**:

```
  getQueryParam() {
    var queryParam = {};
    queryParam['abc'] = this.some_variable;
    return queryParam;
  }
```

Comment: This solution works for Angular, but the question is about AngularJS.

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be related to this:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/5930b8ee27e441aa4422d9174dcc7eb7db30e400.

Which is saying it is a known issue with Angular.

Answer (score 0):

Upon research, we have found that Drupal render forms using a function called request_uri(), which does not encode the output. Consequently, the action url causes angular to error when it loads on the page.

The solution to this we found is adding in a redirect.